# Cannot connect from elsewhere than a console

Tags: mysql, mariadb, linux, connectivity

I am quite a beginner with MySQL, but I already got problems with setting up a connection. I tried to use MySQL Workbench, but I can't connect to the server. I use SparkyLinux, a Debian-based distribution. Here is what I did so far :

1. I created a user and checked that I could log in a console :

   ```
   adrien@sahelantropus:~$ mysql -u adrien -p

   Enter password: 

   Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
   Your MariaDB connection id is 6
   Server version: 10.1.23-MariaDB-9+deb9u1 Debian 9.0

   Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.
   Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input 
   statement.

   MariaDB [(none)]>
   ```

   (maybe it is interesting to notice I can either give my password or not, and log in with exactly the same output)
2. I tried to setup a connection with MySQL Workbench, but when I test it, I get the following output :

   > Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user adrien
   >   Access denied for user 'adrien'@'localhost'
3. I tried to use MySQL Connector in Python, and got the following exception :

   > 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'adrien'@'localhost'

I am sorry if something obvious is going on and I cannot see it, and I thank anyone who could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `mysql` doesn't listen the TCP sockets at all and console client is connected via filesocket. Try to list all network sockets listened at your host:

```
ss -l | grep 3306
```

The other possibility is that you have turned `skip_name_resolve` variable `ON` that disable using of `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. `ss -l | grep 3306` gives no answer at all.